# What are your responsibilities if a student announces their intention to commit a crime?

Tags: teaching, legal-issues

As a faculty member, it can happen that a student tells you that they are intending to commit a crime (while also attempting to swear you to secrecy). This might be something as simple as buying illegal drugs but it may also be something more serious.

It seems you might have three sources of responsibility.  A moral one to do the right thing, a second responsibility to follow university guidance and potentially a legal responsibility to report the intention.

Assuming the university has no clear policy on this question, what is the right and legal thing to do?

Comment: This will depend wildly on the type of crime and will not depend so much on whether there is an academic relationship between you two...

Comment: @wimi One question is if there is some implied duty of care within a university that wouldn't apply in other contexts. Another is if the situation is different for students under 18.

Comment: On matters of self-harm or harm: you need to act. On matters of a victimless crime - the situation is more delicate, because as academic you are a crossing between an official or semi-official, and a confessor. Strictly spoken, however, you do not have the secrecy protection in place that a priest, a lawyer or a journalist enjoys and therefore, the person confiding in you has put you in an ethically impossible situation.

Comment: Are your students adults? If yes, is there written informationen by the institution? If no, why should it be different than if you were, say, a yoga teacher?

Comment: This question is too broad.  Mandatory reporter laws vary from place to place and crime to crime.

Comment: @user111388 At least in Italy, the answer is yes, it is different if you are a university professor or a yoga teacher, because a yoga teacher is not a civil officer (see my answer).

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: But this is not written down in the university papers?

Comment: @user111388 Which university papers? That rule is written down in Italian laws, which trump any university regulations.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: I must say I find it strange that they don't mention the fact that profs are civil officers in university regulations. I would have hoped/assumed that universities make their employees aware of such facts.

Comment: My own institution (in the United States) has a behavioral response team to deal with just such circumstances.  Perhaps yours does, too.

Comment: @Anush  Here's their own description: "The Behavioral Response Team (BRT)  takes a planned approach to identifying and assisting individuals who are distressed and/or exhibiting abnormal, threatening, or dangerous behavior. Through early identification, the team can connect individuals of concern with the resources they need to succeed and hopefully prevent crises. The BRT is a multidisciplinary team that meets regularly to assess and manage concerns that have been brought to the attention of the team."

Comment: @user111388 Since it's by law, you're expected to know the law (even though the Italian law is not so clear about our duties and rights: I once tried to better understand what are my legal responsibilities toward the students in case of an emergency, but I couldn't find a clear answer).

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano: I do not know Italian regulations, but in my own country words like "professors" are a little bit blurry - not everyone means the same when speaking about them. Thus, I would have hoped that people who are  civil officers would be told by their institution so such that they can look up the law. Is it completely clear in Italy who is a professor/civil officer?

Comment: @user111388 Yes, in Italy that of professor is a well-defined category. I think I've been known that professors are civil officers since I was at middle school.

Answer (score 8):

> what is the right and legal thing to do

I think this question mixes two different concerns: The right thing to do is a matter of personal ethical judgement. The legal thing to do is, well, a matter of law.

One might argue that the ethical concern is more fundamental than the legal one, since "I will do whatever the law requires me to do" is already an ethical statement -- and, depending on the case, a highly problematic one: History is full of examples where laws were set up in a way that was clearly not *right* -- from our view as citizens in modern societies today, and from the view of ethically-minded individuals who initiated changes to these laws.

One's personal ethical judgement, however, will depend on the case at hand, unless one takes the shortcut of just doing whatever the law requires one to do.

Answer (score 7):

"What is the legal thing to do" depends on the jurisdiction. In Italy, for instance, during your job as a professor or instructor you have the role of a civil officer (*pubblico ufficiale*), and obligated to report all criminal offences (*reati*) (relevant law: [art. 361 c.p.](https://www.brocardi.it/codice-penale/libro-secondo/titolo-iii/capo-i/art361.html)).

On the other hand, since you make that example, buying a modest amount of drugs for personal use (below a given threshold depending on the exact substance) is *not* considered a *reato*, but just a milder offence.

Comment: Does that include reporting when people say they intend to commit a crime in the future? (Note my use of the word *illegal*. There must be some drugs that are illegal to buy in Italy?)

Comment: @fomin Ah, good point, I don't think so.

Comment: @fomin It might count as planning to commit a crime, which in some places for some crimes can be itself illegal. If the student tries to enlist your help in violently overthrowing the state, that certainly sounds like conspiracy to commit treason. When it's just about drugs for personal use, probably not so much though.

Answer (score 4):

If you were a priest, psychologist, etc., people talking to you in that capacity have a reasonable expectation of privacy and confidentiality (though I believe that the confidentiality *can* be broken if it involves an intent to commit a *future* crime that will directly *harm* someone).

But if someone says something to a professional who is not acting in that capacity (e.g. a conversation at a party), there is no reasonable expectation of privacy.

In your case, it's unlikely that the plan to commit a crime is related to your relationship as a professor.  Asking you to keep it secret happens at the personal level, not professional level. So how you choose to deal with the knowledge should be no different that how you would handle it if an acquaintance at the gym had told you the same thing.

On the other hand, if the crime *is* related to your official relationship, failing to report it could make you complicit.  As an extreme example, suppose your student tells you he is going to abduct people to perform experiments for his thesis.

The fundamental issue is *why* the student told you this information.